# How to achieve good Topology

Tags: modeling, sculpting, topology

[image: facial topology]

What's the best way to create good typology like the above example has? Is it achieved through retopology or can you be accurate while modeling and sculpting?

Comment: Solid modeling skills are enough.

Comment: It is possible to model (of course) but sculpt then retopo is a much more comfortable workflow.  There's a [great tutorial by FlippedNormals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM) about retopo.